# Save two different images at the same time on firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I try to save two different images at the same time at one storage location

This is my function to save the information

```
var text: String = ""
var addedByUser: String?
var userImage: UIImage?
var jobImage: UIImage!
var downloadURL: String?
var userDownloadURL: String?
let ref: DatabaseReference!

init(text: String? = nil, jobImage: UIImage? = nil, addedByUser: String? = nil, userImage: UIImage? = nil) {
    self.text = text!
    self.jobImage = jobImage
    self.addedByUser = addedByUser
    self.userImage = userImage
    ref = Database.database().reference().child("jobs").childByAutoId()
}

init(snapshot: DataSnapshot){
    ref = snapshot.ref
    if let value = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] {
        text = value["text"] as! String
        addedByUser = value["addedByUser"] as? String
        downloadURL = value["imageDownloadURL"] as? String
        userDownloadURL = value["imageUserDownloadURL"] as? String
    }
}

func save() {
    let newPostKey = ref.key

    // save jobImage
    if let imageData = jobImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5) {
        let storage = Storage.storage().reference().child("jobImages/\(newPostKey)")

        storage.putData(imageData).observe(.success, handler: { (snapshot) in
            self.downloadURL = snapshot.metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
            let postDictionary = [
                "imageDownloadURL" : self.downloadURL!,
                "imageUserDownloadURL" : self.userDownloadURL!,
                "text" : self.text,
                "addedByUser" : self.addedByUser!
                ] as [String : Any]
            self.ref.setValue(postDictionary)
        })
    }
}
```

I tried following code

```
if let imageData = jobImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5), ((userImage?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)) != nil) {
```

But it's not working as then nothing get's saved in the database...

Do you have any ideas how I can solve it?

Comment: The code in your question doesn't appear to be related to saving two images at the same time. Also, you're adding an observer, which would generally return a handle for the upload so you can determine its progress, pause it etc. It doesn't look like you are using that at all. So what about just following the example code in the [Firebase Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files#upload_from_a_local_file) on uploading files? Can you clarify what you mean by 'two different images'?

Comment: I've done all that but I thought I shouldn't post all the code as for me only these lines seems to be important, but as you wanted to, I uploaded the other code snippet.

Comment: Also, how can I put one then more image inside the data?

Comment: Yes - you should only post the minimum code needed to duplicate the issue. What you have in the question is fine. However, as I mentioned above, there's no correlation between the code in your question and saving two images. Also what does *put one then more image inside the data* mean? What data? What are you trying to accomplish? If you can clarify the question we may be able to help.

Comment: Ok so this might get a longer message then it should be but I'm new to all this why I got a few problems in explaining, I hope you can understand this. What I want to accomplish is to upload not only a from the user taken (in my case named) jobImage to the Firebase Storage, I also want to upload to userProfileImage (in my case named userImage) to the storage. Now I declared the uploadedImageData as imageData with an compressionQualtiy of 0.5 to manage the upload to the firebase storage here "        storage.putData(imageData).observe(.success, handler: { (snapshot) in
"

Comment: But as you see I only declared one Image (the jobImage) there, now I would like to add a second image (the userImage) to the imageData, so I created this line "if let imageData = jobImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5), ((userImage?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)) != nil) {
" but through this code, I'm not able to post anything as Firebase probably won't recognize what I'm trying to do. So long story short I would like to upload the user and jobImage through one function... I hope you understand now what I mean

Comment: I also thought about using an arrayOfImages but this array won't recognize the UIImage

Comment: You should really update your question with the additional info. But.... Are you trying to upload *two* images to the same storage location? If so, that won't really work without some kind of encoding scheme, which you probably won't want to do. It's one image per node.

Comment: Yes haha that's what I want to do - is there a way to upload it on another location but within the same save() function?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the question is how do I upload an image to two different locations. It's unclear why there's an observe function so this answer ignores that as it may not be needed.

Starting with your code, your save function will look like this

```
func save() {
   self.uploadImageTask(imageName: "my_image.png", toLocation: "jobImage")
   self.uploadImageTask(imageName: "my_image.png", toLocation: "anotherLocation")
}
```

and then the upload function

```
func uploadImageTask(imageName: String, toLocation: String) {
    let theImage = UIImage(named: imageName) //set up your image here
    let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(theImage)! //we're doing a PNG
    let storage = Storage.storage()
    let storageRef = storage.reference()
    let locationRef = storageRef.child("images").child(toLocation)
    let imageLocationRef = locationRef.child(imageName)

    // Upload the file to the path "images/location/imageName"
    let uploadTask = locationRef.putData(data, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
        guard let metadata = metadata else {
            print("error while uploading")
            return
        }
        let size = metadata.size // Metadata contains file metadata such as size, content-type.
        print(size)
        locationRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
            guard let downloadURL = url else {
                print("an error occured after uploading and then downloading")
                return
            }
            let x = downloadURL.absoluteString
            print(x) //or build a dict and save to Firebase
        }
    }
}
```

the result is an image stored at

```
/images/jobImage/my_image.png
/images/anotherLocation/my_image.png
```

and it will also print the path to each image, which could be stored in Firebase.